# CodeIgnite change default database name on the fly

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have codeigniter setup to connect to 2 databases (default and site). I need to change the default database name dynamically and anything that uses the default connection should also use the new database. Is there a way to do this?

The reason for this is I want to setup a cron script that runs commands on certain databases. I need to be able to dynamically change this and editing application/config/database.php is not possible.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
$phppos_client_name = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '.'));

$db['site']['hostname'] = 'php-pos-db';
$db['site']['username'] = 'phppoint';
$db['site']['password'] = 'password';
$db['site']['database'] = 'phppoint_site';
$db['site']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['site']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['site']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['site']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['site']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['site']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['site']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['site']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['site']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['site']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['site']['stricton'] = FALSE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = "php-pos-db";
$db['default']['username'] = "phppoint";
$db['default']['password'] = "password";
$db['default']['database'] = "phppoint_$phppos_client_name";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "phppos_";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;


/* End of file database.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/database.php */
```

Comment: `$this->load->database('site')`

Comment: Will `$this->load->database('DB_NAME') allow all database queries in the program to use that database for rest of execution? Is it really that simple?

Comment: `DB_NAME` does not mean the database name.Its the variable name inside your database config.Here your case its `default` or `site`

Comment: So If I add the configuration to the file; it will work? If I have 100 of these will this cause any performance problems?

Comment: If you want all run-time queries to use this database then you could load it in `MY_controller`'s constructor. If you wanted the system to use it, then you would need to create a `hook`

Answer (score 1):

The way you want I think its not possible. you can do it alternative way.

1.Do not load database at your autoload config.
  2.load your database manually using `$this->load->database('site')` or `$this->load->database('default')` before executing query.

Answer (score 0):

3 approaches (there could be many though)

1. Read the whole file, save it as fileName.txt (having the updated database name) and rename the file as database.php
2. Where will you store the database name (if it is in a file, read the value from file and place it here in the php)?. You will have to make it messy by adding the code here in this file
3. if you saving the database name into another database (that code would be static), fetch the name and save into a $var variable and assign it in the config.

Comment: 1. This is not an option as I only want to affect a script run from CLI. The other actions of the program need to use the database.php file as is.

2. I currently use database.php to pull the subdomain from the url to load the right database.

3. I don't understand this

Answer (score 0):

The db specification for the entire Code Igniter app depends on the config specification and this can't be changed dynamically. This lives inside the system, it's not allowed to be modified unless you modify it with a text editor.

I would over-ride the db name in the application code dynamically by putting:

```
$this->load->database('db1')
```

on 2nd dynamic catch include:

```
$this->load->database('db2')
```

Comment: But I could just add the database to the configuration and it will work right?

Comment: it will work, and you can specify multiple db's but only one will be used by default. if the dymanic code is going to be in your app code, you can dynamically load the dbs.

Answer (score 0):

```
class CronModel extends CI_Model 
{
    public function run()
    {
        // The default database configuration $db['default']
        $query1 = $this->db->query();

        // pass true as second param to use active record
        // ie : $site->select()->get();
        $site = $this->load->database('site', true);

        // The site database configuration $db['site']
        $query2 = $site->query();
    }
}
```